# SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer on line 12

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to make my first Discord bot. It only has one command so far, which is the "ping" command.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = ',';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`); // here
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is w!')
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

I get the syntax error on this line:

```js
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
```

I am probably doing something stupid but I just can't tell what.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not coming from your ping command's file? This one looks correct, and there is shorthands either :)

Comment: It's coming from main.js   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dares\OneDrive\Desktop\MoonBot\main.js:12:21)

Comment: Can you show the entire stack trace? It looks like the error does indeed come from one of your command modules.